# UWP blank GridView with header and line between each column

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

[I just want a blank GridView with header in UWP using XAML. It must contain line between each column till certain height.The Grid will look like this.
I appreciate any advices. Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZX5P.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new DataGrid control that is currently being worked on by Microsoft itself. It is available via NuGet as a prerelease package, but should be available as a normal control later on. You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/datagrid#sample-code)

Documentation is not plenty given that it is quite new, but it does work in very similar ways to the WPF DataGrid control. You can find more information about how the WPF control works [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html).